# How to get the most frequent values from list in MATLAB (but multiple values)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

From 1 dimensional matrix:

```
list_A = [1,2,4,6,7,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,13,13,13]
```

How can i get the list of number that have a highest occurrence (in this case occurrence = 3)

The answer that i want should be like this (if we use list_A):

```
Ans = [7,11,13]
```

Comment: Have a look at my edits, there are some other possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [**`hist`**](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/hist.html):

I assumed your vector `A` is sorted.

```
A = [1,2,4,6,7,7,7,9,10,11,11,11,13,13,13];
occ = 3;

out = A( hist(A,A) == occ )
```

gives:

```
out =

     7    11    13
```

---

If `A` is not sorted, you could sort it of course, or:

```
A = [7,7,7,1,2,4,6,9,10,11,11,11,13,13,13]
occ = 3;

out = find( histc(A,1:max(A)) == occ )
```

---

If there are also negative numbers:

```
A = [7,7,7,-4,6,-9,10,-11,-11,-11,13,13,13,-20]
occ = 3;

out = find( histc(A,min(A):max(A)) == occ ) + min(A)-1
```

or the simple version is working too:

```
A = sort(A);
out = A( hist(A,A) == occ )

>> out =  -11     7    13
```

---

Another convenient way is to use the `tabulate` function of the Statistics Toolbox, **which would even work for decimal values!**

```
A = [7.5,7.5,7.5,-4,6,-9,10,-11,-11,-11,13,13,13,-20]
occ = 3;

T = tabulate(A);
out = T(T(:,2) == occ  ,1)

>> out =

  -11.0000
    7.5000
   13.0000
```

Comment: +1 Already, but curious now for the unsorted case with negative numbers.

Comment: Explicit usage of `sort` makes sense to me :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it most easily with [`mode`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mode.html). To get *all* values you should use the third output, which will be a cell array:

```
[~, ~, result] = mode(list_A);
result = result{1}.';
```

---

EDIT

If your vector is already sorted and you want to exploit that (which `mode` apparently doesn't do), you can do it manually with  `diff`, `find` and `max`:

```
ii = find(diff([list_A inf]));
dii = diff(ii);
result = list_A(ii(find(dii==max(dii))+1));
```

Comment: `mode` makes sense here!

Comment: wow! and it's even a standard function! you're limited to the most frequent values, but that's what the title said.